# Firefox plugin: gapi.client is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, firefox-addon-webextensions, google-api-js-client

I've tried a bunch of suggested solutions from stackoverflow but none works, I suspect it may be something to do with cookies or new versions, so I have to ask at long last:

I'm trying to use Google (Sheets specifically) API in my firefox web extension, and I've downloaded this: https://apis.google.com/js/api.js
and added it into my manifest.json under "background" - "scripts" before my own script as you can see in the source code below.
Here is the tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append

My entire project is too big, so I recreated the problem on a smaller scale:

test.js:

```
function onCreated() {
  if (browser.runtime.lastError) { console.log(`Error: ${browser.runtime.lastError}`); }
  else { console.log("Item created successfully"); }
  gapi.client.setApiKey('testkey'); //This is the line that doesn't work
}

browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "testlbl",
  title: "TEST LABEL - CLICK ME",
  contexts: ["all"]
}, onCreated);

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if(info.menuItemId == "testlbl") {
      console.log("ACTION TRIGGERED");
      console.log("JQUERY RESULT: "+$(location).attr('href'));
  }
});
```

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Testing",
    "description": "Random stuff",
    "version": "1.0",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["api.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "test.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
      "contextMenus",
      "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

messages.json:

```
{
  "extensionName": {
    "message": "TestLabel",
    "description": "Name of the extension."
  }

}
```

folder structure(in case you need it to test):

```
mainFolder
--- test.js
--- api.js
--- jquery-3.3.1.min.js
--- manifest.json
--- _locales
------ en
--------- messages.json
```

I tried adding JQuery the same way as you can also see, just to make sure I was adding the scripts correctly, and it works fine. I downloaded it from here:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

The downloading was suggested as a solution here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#resourceLoading

The problem is that I get "*gapi.client is undefined*" in the browser console and nothing happening as a result. I've only put in the line `gapi.client.setApiKey('testkey');` to test the Google API and narrow the problem down.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, how about adding this library ``https://apis.google.com/js/client.js``? Or replace ``api.js`` to ``client.js``? If these didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't fix the problem. It also brought up some other issues, so I think api.js is the right one.

Comment: By the way, from your question, if you will append values to Spreadsheet using [the method of spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append), API key cannot be used for this situation. Because API key can use only GET method for Sheets API. So please use OAuth2 or Service Account. When you retrieve values from Spreadsheet, you can retrieve values using API key by publicly sharing the Spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that in the real project and have set permissions in my google account, generated API key, client ID, set scope, set parameters(INSERT_ROWS, RAW..)etc., but I still get "gapi.client is undefined".

Comment: I am investigating a similar issue. Have you tried `gapi.load("client")`?

Comment: I haven't tried that. I ended up using a nodejs server instead as an in-between, and implemented Google's library for NodeJS to Sheets. I make API calls to the server from my extension.